# The variance of the number of runs in the runs up and down test

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, variance

Consider random permutations of $1,2,\ldots,n$ and let $R=1,\ldots,n-1$ be the number of runs in the permuted sequence. For example, if $n=6$, the sequence
$$
6\quad2\quad4\quad5\quad3\quad1
$$
corresponds to the sequence $-,+,+,-,-$ and consist of three runs.

> The expected value and the variance of the number of runs are given by
> $$
> \operatorname ER=\frac{2n-1}3
> \qquad\text{and}\qquad
> \operatorname{Var}R=\frac{16n-29}{90}.
> $$
> How is the expression for the variance of $R$ derived?

There is a number of places on the Internet where these expression are given without a derivation (for example, [here](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Exmeng/Course/CS6337/Note/master/node44.html)). The derivation of the expected value is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839650/23249), but there is no derivation of the variance. It seems that we need to calculate the second moment of the sum of the indicators (defined as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839650/23249)) but I am struggling to compute the expected value $\operatorname E[I_iI_j]$ with $i\ne j$. $I_i$ and $I_j$ do not seem to be independent so this complicates things but I might be missing something.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indicators whose positions don’t overlap are independent (since all $6$ permutations of three values being equiprobable is a local fact that doesn’t depend on which other values are taken at other positions), so we only have to consider a few local correlations.

For the variance, we can ignore the first and last indicators that have constant values $1$ and $0$, respectively. There are $n-2$ remaining indicators, and for each distance $k$ there are $n-2-k$ pairs at that distance.

At distance $k=0$, we have $\mathsf E[I_iI_i]=\mathsf E[I_i]=\frac23$.

At distance $k=1$, we have

$$\mathsf E[I_iI_{i+1}]=\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\lt y_i\gt y_{i+1}\lt y_{i+1})+\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\gt y_i\lt y_{i+1}\gt y_{i+1})=\frac5{12}\;.$$

(You can check that each of the two conditions is satisfied by $5$ out of the $24$ equiprobable permutations.)

At distance $k=2$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E[I_iI_{i+2}]
&=&\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\lt y_i\gt y_{i+1}\lt y_{i+1}\gt y_{i+2})+\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\lt y_i\gt y_{i+1}\gt y_{i+1}\lt y_{i+2})+{}\\&&\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\gt y_i\lt y_{i+1}\lt y_{i+1}\gt y_{i+2})+\mathsf P(y_{i-1}\gt y_i\lt y_{i+1}\gt y_{i+1}\lt y_{i+2})
\\[4pt]
&=&\frac{16+11+11+16}{5!}
\\
&=&\frac9{20}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

(Here I used a computer – not because it can’t be done by hand; it just seemed too error-prone.)

At distance $k\gt2$ we have

$$\mathsf E[I_iI_{i+k}]=\mathsf E[I_i]\mathsf E[I_{i+k}]=\frac49\;.$$

So adding it all up, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathsf E\left[\left(\sum_iI_i\right)^2\right]
&=&
\mathsf E\left[\sum_{ij}I_iI_j\right]
\\
&=&(n-2)\cdot\frac23+2(n-3)\cdot\frac5{12}+2(n-4)\cdot\frac9{20}\\&&+\left((n-2)^2-(n-2)-2(n-3)-2(n-4)\right)\cdot\frac49
\\
&=&
\frac49n^2-\frac85n+\frac{131}{90}\;,
\end{eqnarray}

so the variance is

$$
\frac49n^2-\frac85n+\frac{131}{90}-\left(\frac{2(n-2)}3\right)^2=\frac{16n-29}{90}\;.
$$